# Weird proof obligations resulting from a push/pop evaluator in Coq

Tags: coq, proof, dependent-type, proof-obligation

I'm trying to define a simple stack-based language in Coq. For now, the instruction set contains `push` which pushes a `nat`, and an instruction `pop` which pops one. The idea is that programs are dependently typed; `Prog 2` is a program which leaves two elements on the stack after execution.

This is implemented by this simple program:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Vectors.VectorDef.

Inductive Prog : nat -> Type :=
  | push : forall n : nat, nat -> Prog n -> Prog (S n)
  | pop  : forall n : nat, Prog (S n) -> Prog n.

Fixpoint eval (n : nat) (p : Prog n) : t nat n :=
  match p with
  | push _ n p => cons _ n _ (eval _ p)
  | pop _ p => match eval _ p with
    | cons _ _ _ stack => stack
    end
  end.
```

I now want to add an instruction `pop'` which pops an element of the stack but can only be applied when there are at least two elements on the stack.

```coq
Inductive Prog : nat -> Type :=
  | push : forall n : nat, nat -> Prog n -> Prog (S n)
  | pop' : forall n : nat, Prog (S (S n)) -> Prog (S n).
```

When using the same `Fixpoint` as above (changing `pop` to `pop'`) I get the error

> The term "stack" has type "t nat n0" while it is expected to have type "t nat (S k)".

So I thought I could do this with `Program`. So I use:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Program.Tactics Coq.Logic.JMeq.

Program Fixpoint eval (n : nat) (p : Prog n) : t nat n :=
  match p with
  | push _ n p => cons _ n _ (eval _ p)
  | pop' k p => match eval _ p with
    | cons _ l _ stack => stack
    | nil _ => _
    end
  end.
```

However, for some reason this generates weird obligations, which I don't think can be solved. The first (of two) obligations left after automatic attempts is:

```
k : nat
p0 : Prog (S k)
p : Prog (S (S k))
Heq_p : JMeq (pop' k p) p0
l, n0 : nat
stack : t nat n0
h : nat
t : t nat n0
Heq_anonymous0 : JMeq (cons nat l n0 stack) (cons nat h n0 t)
______________________________________(1/1)
n0 = S k
```

I don't see a way to link the `k`, which is the type argument for `Prog`, and the `n0`, which is the type argument for the vector type `t`.

Why does this `Program` yield this weird obligation, and how can I write the evaluation function circumventing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get `Program Fixpoint` to remember the appropriate equality, but here's a definition using tactics, where we can use `remember` to create a convoy pattern around an equality proof. The two subproofs in the proof term were generated by `abstract`; they're both really simple proofs about constructors.

```
Fixpoint eval (n : nat) (p : Prog n) : t nat n.
  refine (match p with
          | push n' v p' => cons _ v _ (eval _ p')
          | pop' n' p' => _
          end).
  set (x := eval _ p').
  remember (S (S n')).
  destruct x.
  abstract congruence. (* nil case *)
  assert (n0 = S n') by (abstract congruence).
  rewrite H in x.
  exact x.
Defined.

Print eval.
(*
eval =
fix eval (n : nat) (p : Prog n) {struct p} :
t nat n :=
  match p in (Prog n0) return (t nat n0) with
  | push n' v p' => cons nat v n' (eval n' p')
  | pop' n' p' =>
      let x := eval (S (S n')) p' in
      let n0 := S (S n') in
      let Heqn0 : n0 = S (S n') := eq_refl in
      match
        x in (t _ n1)
        return (n1 = S (S n') -> Prog n1 -> t nat (S n'))
      with
      | nil _ =>
          fun (Heqn1 : 0 = S (S n')) (_ : Prog 0) =>
          eval_subproof n' Heqn1
      | cons _ _ n1 x0 =>
          fun (Heqn1 : S n1 = S (S n')) (_ : Prog (S n1)) =>
          let H : n1 = S n' := eval_subproof0 n' n1 Heqn1 in
          let x1 :=
            eq_rec n1 (fun n2 : nat => t nat n2) x0 (S n') H in
          x1
      end Heqn0 p'
  end
     : forall n : nat, Prog n -> t nat n
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question, note it is impossible to write any program in your language!  (It does not have any effect on the issue you are describing, but it is still worth pointing it out anyway...)

```
From Coq Require Import Vectors.Vector.

Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive Prog : nat -> Type :=
  | push : forall n : nat, nat -> Prog n -> Prog (S n)
  | pop' : forall n : nat, Prog (S (S n)) -> Prog (S n).

Fixpoint not_Prog n (p : Prog n) : False :=
  match p with
  | push _ p' => not_Prog p'
  | pop'   p' => not_Prog p'
  end.
```

Now, to your question.  It is because of this and related issues that many people prefer to avoid this style of programming in Coq.  In this case, I find it easier to program your function using `tl`, which extracts the tail of a vector.

```
From Coq Require Import Vectors.Vector.

Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive Prog : nat -> Type :=
  | empty : Prog 0
  | push : forall n : nat, nat -> Prog n -> Prog (S n)
  | pop' : forall n : nat, Prog (S (S n)) -> Prog (S n).

Fixpoint eval (n : nat) (p : Prog n) : t nat n :=
  match p with
  | empty    => nil _
  | push n p => cons _ n _ (eval p)
  | pop'   p => tl (eval p)
  end.
```

If you are still interested in working with this kind of datatype in Coq, you might want to have a look at the [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations) plugin, which provides better support for dependent pattern matching.

Comment: FWIW, I tried to implement `eval` using the Equations plugin, but I believe I tripped on something that causes [issue #91](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations/issues/91).

Comment: @AntonTrunov I also tried to use Equations, but did not encounter any problem. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try using Equations.

```
From Coq Require Import Vector.
From Equations Require Import Equations.

Equations eval (n : nat) (p : Prog n) : t nat n :=
  eval _ (push _ n p) := cons n (eval _ p);
  eval _ (pop' _ p) <= eval _ p => {
    eval _ (pop' _ p) (cons _ stack) := stack }.
```

But note that I am not totally sure of what I am doing.

Comment: I think you are right. AFAIR, I used that pattern like so: `(cons h stack)` and got an error about inaccessibility of `h`. So, maybe it's not the issue I linked to in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315329/weird-proof-obligations-resulting-from-a-push-pop-evaluator-in-coq#comment87714667_50332353). I'm a bit out of context now, but it doesn't seem that the head is necessarily fixed unlike the length of the vector.

Comment: Indeed, I get the error you described. What is strange is that we can put `_` on the left-side and on the right-side, and they are completed correctly. Maybe the typing information is enough.